# awk standalone script not working as opposed to command line version

Tags: awk

I have a one line (g)awk script that works as intended:

```
'/pattern/ {$n="new string"}1'
```

Now, I'd like to have the above in a standalone (g)awk script, together with other commands, so far I failed in understanding how to make it work.

My file starts with:

```
BEGIN {
FS = ","
OFS = FS
}

{
here goes my code
}
```

In particular I'm not sure where to put the /pattern/ (inside or outside brackets) given the slightly different syntax of the code - but maybe here is where I get it wrong.

I have the same doubt on the placement of the '1'.

---

So I'm updating this as I'm not sure the above is clear enough - my fault.

What I have is a CSV file with 4 fields (1-4), I'd like to match a specific pattern in field #3 and on that pattern being matched, replace all of that field content with a new string.

In a (g)awk one liner I can do that, with the following:

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," '/pattern/ {$3="new string"}1
```

I'd like to move the above code in a awk script, where other commands will be present, so to achieve the same result - that is:

input file:

```
yellow, yellow and blue, yellow and red, blue
blue, yellow and blue, yellow and red, red
red, yellow and red, blue and red, blue
red, yellow and blue, yellow and blue, red
```

pattern: red
interested field: #3
new string: tree

desired output:

```
yellow, yellow and blue, tree, blue
blue, yellow and blue, tree, red
red, yellow and red, tree, blue
red, yellow and blue, yellow and blue, red
```

Comment: title is a little bit misleading, since there is no script counterpart to the oneline. Can I suggest to try and come back with a better title?

Comment: it should be something like this `awk -v n=6 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}/pattern/{$n="new string"}1' file`

Comment: Another problem: `$n` means the value of the variable having as name the value contained in `n`. Since `n` is not defined, its value is `0` and so `$n` means `$0` in this case. This is a rather cryptic way to mean `$0`. When I was writing this, kvantour corrected this by setting n to some value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AWK script has three sections - **BEGIN**, **BODY** and **END**. Your oneliner was using only the body part. The script equivalent is like this:

```
BEGIN {
  FS = ","
  OFS = FS
}

/pattern/ {
    print $1,$2,"new string",$3
}

!/pattern/ {
  print $0
}
```

The body syntax itself can repeat:

```
/pattern1/ {
    action 1
}

/pattern2/ {
    action 2
}
```

Comment: The `1` at the end stands for a new body instruction meaning "if true (1) then print the whole line" (which is the default action when the `{}` part is left out). This implies that the pattern can be replaced by a condition.

Comment: Trying the above, the result is not as intended, **all** $n are replaced into the value provided in the $n="new_string", as opposed to only replacing those records where the /pattern/ is matched.

`BEGIN {
  FS = ","
  OFS = FS
}

/pattern/ {
    $3="new_string"
}1`

Intended result:

Records with the matching /pattern/:

`$1 unchanged,$2 unchanged, $3 new_string, $4 unchanged`

Records not matching /pattern/:

`$1 unchanged,$2 unchanged, $3 unchanged, $4 unchanged`

Comment: You need a block that matches other. I updated the proposed script

Comment: @kofemann: In the current state of your code, non matching lines are printed twice, due to the presence of the `1` behind `}` and matching lines are printed correctly once and without substitution, twice more.

Comment: @PierreFrançois Right. fixed.